# To get full stack trace from Method profiling

Tags: java, performance, jfr, azul-zulu

I have been poking the AZUL JFR profiler to see gaps in my system. But i am not able to get full trace of the call being made.
[image: JFR Image]
Now since the trace is only till HashMap, how can i get which method is calling it ?

Comment: Try [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/), it usually yields more accurate stack traces. If the problem remains, use [Java method profiling](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/#java-method-profiling) option to find the exact callers of `java.util.HashMap$TreeNode.putTreeVal`

Comment: Ok let me check that.